# devtodev - Modifying the query to aggregate the values based on a declared variable

Tags: postgresql

This is my basic query:

```
SELECT 
  eventtime::date AS p_date, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABC
FROM 
  310189
GROUP BY 
 p_date
ORDER BY 
  p_date;
```

Which outputs a chart like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH2BN.png).

I want to modify this query to aggregate the values of ABC based on the value of the declared variable. For example if the variable is set to 7 it will aggragate on a weekly basis(7 days groupings).

I know how to declare the variable:

DECLARE @aggregation_days INT;
SET @aggregation_days = 1

I'm not sure how to modify the query to account for it.

I've tried using a case statement but it didn't work. i also don't think this is the best approach anyway.

I've also tried to use a date_trunc function but that didn't work.

Would it be possible to use a generate_series function to do this?

Comment: 1) This `DECLARE @aggregation_days INT; SET @aggregation_days = 1` is not Postgres syntax. I'm guessing this is something from SQL Server Tsql. 2) You can use DECLARE inside a function/procedure though not with `@`.  See [Declarations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) 3) Show what your tried in the CASE and what the error message was. **Add information as text to your question text**.

Comment: I figured that a case statement is not good because I can only use discriminate values. 

I want something that will let me aggregate the results based on whatever integer is assigned to the variable. 

You are also right about declaring the variable. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

In the following query, I adjusted the `eventtime` of each record to the start of its aggregation period based on a variable number of days (e.g., 7 for weekly grouping) and then grouped and summed the data accordingly.

```
-- Replace 7 with whatever aggregation period you need
WITH params AS (
    SELECT 7 AS aggregation_days
)
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', (eventtime - INTERVAL '1 day' * (EXTRACT(DAY FROM eventtime)::int % (SELECT aggregation_days FROM params)))::date) AS p_date_start,
    SUM(CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABC
FROM
    310189
GROUP BY
    p_date_start
ORDER BY
    p_date_start;
```